# How do I retrieve the groovy pipeline script used by one jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for an API call that would allow me to retrieve the pipeline script that was use by a specific Jenkins build.

Please note that this may be different than the pipeline script defined in the job definition, as this could have being changed between builds.

This script is stored by Jenkins because `/replay` plugin allows you to replay a pipeline (the original version used by a specific build).

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround for this was to parse the HTML of that page with something like:

```
curl -n --silent $JOB/replay/ | \
    xmllint --nowarning --html --xpath "//textarea/text()" > Jenkinsfile
```

Yes, us ugly, but it did work. I would be more than happy to see that someone comes with a proper REST API call solution.

Comment: You should put the pipeline into a `Jenkinsfile` inside the repository..

Comment: I don't think this will also fetch any `load`ed scripts, but this is a good start to a good question.